# Should some tags require other tags to make sense?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I have recently reviewed [this suggested tag edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18984461)

It seems to suggest that the WinForms tag cannot be used without providing the framework it is referring to (Mono or .Net). I rejected that edit with the note that tags should potentially be usable on their own and not require other tags to make sense otherwise we should e.g. split WinForms to WinForms-Net and WinForms-Mono . However now I am not 100% confident on this decision.

Should I have approved it? Is it OK for tags to require other tags?

Comment: When you are unsure, use the Skip button.

Comment: @BDL here's the thing. I was sure at the time, but now I'm having second thoughts.

Comment: Tags can and will sometimes only make sense when combined witha language or framework tag. We don't need [python-strings] [javascript-strings] [java-strings] etc. Its not bad or good, it's just part of how the system works.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think you've misunderstood my point. The [strings] tag refers to the abstract data type of string and therefore there could be sensible questions regarding a string as an abstract data type that do not require any other tag to make sense. My point was regarding tags that cannot possible make any sense under any circumstances when there's no accompanying tag (from a distinct set of appropriate accompanying tags). In that case, I am wondering, to prevent users from using nonsensical tags we should ensure that each tag makes sense on its own and other tags help clarify?

Comment: A language agnostic question about strings would still require the [tag:language-agnostic] tag. There are [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms+-mono+-.net?sort=votes&pageSize=50) highly voted questions that include [tag:winforms] while excluding both [tag:mono] and [tag:.net], which leads me to believe that the edit might have been well-intentioned but wrong. Regardless, my point stands. If a question doesn't make sense because it is missing an accompanying tag, you could either ask the author for clarification, or make an educated guess based on the information at hand.

Comment: "WinForms" feels like a bad example... There are plenty of problems that applicable to both (I'd expect majority of tagged questions to be in that category).